# Minimal Python Build of OpenCV 2.4.3

Tags: python, opencv, build, cmake

I'm using OpenCV's Python bindings to call the function `matchTemplate`. This is the only function I need. In order to be able to call `matchTemplate`, I have to ship OpenCV's python bindings `cv2.pyd` with my (Windows) application, which weighs in at a hefty 9MB.

Is there any way of building (the Python bindings of) OpenCV in such a way that only the modules I require are included in `cv2.pyd`? `matchTemplate` seems to be a part of the `imgproc` module so I assume I'd only really need OpenCV's `core` and `imgproc`.

I already tried playing around with OpenCV's CMake options, and I think I have managed to only have some modules built. However, as soon as I disable a single module, say `calib3d` by setting CMake's `BUILD_OPENCV_calib3d` to false, I also "lose" the Python build. In other words, when I use CMake to generate Visual Studio solution files for building all modules except `calib3d` and *with* `python`, the Visual Studio solution contains all modules but `calib3d` *and* `python`. I tried tinkering with the CMakeLists file of the `python` module by removing `calib3d` from the `ocv_add_module` call

```
ocv_add_module(python BINDINGS opencv_core opencv_flann ...)
```

and the setting of included headers

```
set(opencv_hdrs
    "${OPENCV_MODULE_opencv_core_LOCATION}/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp"
    ...
```

Unfortunately, to no avail. Does anybody know how to do this?

I'm building with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks!

Comment: if all you need is matchTemplate you could always just re-implement that function in native python

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "native" Python. Implementing the function in pure Python is not an option as that would be way too slow. Implementing the function in C/C++ and then calling that from Python would be an option, but is more work. I was hoping to just set some flags of the OpenCV build and get a smaller binary that doesn't contain a lot of the functions I don't need.

Comment: fair enough if speed is an issue then re-implementing in python probably won't help you. Sorry I don't know how you would set the flags.